# Using lazy loading with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use this [lazy loading plugin](http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/) in a backbone app, I adapted the template to work with the plugin and called and the plugin script in but it doesn't work. Here is the jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/swayziak/9R9zU/27/

The template:

```
<script id="bookTemplate" type="text/template">
    <img src="https://www.amrms.com/ssl/iftafoundation/bluepay/Images/Loading_Animation.gif" data-src="<%= image %>"/>
    <h2 class="bookTitle"><%= title %><h2>
</script>
```

And the script on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").unveil();
});
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using incorrect path to the plugin in your fiddle.
Another one thing why it is not working is related to the place where you put plugin initialization. You initialize it on the document ready but your images is not rendered yet. So you have to initialize plugin after rendering the view (when images are added to the DOM).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've updated the path to the plugin and tried to initialize the plugin in the router, in the initialize of the bookListView but nothing works. Here is the fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/swayziak/9R9zU/39/

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with version of Zepto, unveil uses filter function that was updated in  zepto latest version: (from http://zeptojs.com/#changelog)

> New features
>
> ```
>  $.fn.filter(function(index){ ... })
> ```

Check out updated jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/9R9zU/41/)  that uses http://zeptojs.com/zepto.js source.

**EDIT**:

to make the entire example work I moved the unveil call to the view render function (http://jsfiddle.net/9R9zU/52/)

```
app.BookView = Backbone.View.extend ({
  tagName: 'div',
  className: 'book',
  template: _.template( $( '#bookTemplate' ).html()),
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    this.$el.find("img").unveil();//for every render we run the lazy loader
    return this;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't notice that the Zepto version wasn't the last one. But even with that the plugin isn't working properly: when I go to the edit or about page and I return to the list of books, the image of each book doesn't render, it only appears the loading image.

Comment: @user2473588 See Edit and jsfiddle

Comment: Hi, I was trying again this but I think the lady loading doesn't work. When I update the browser it seems that all views all already rendered.